RF coupler to measure output of PA
I want to build a RF coupler in order to measure harmonics after the low pass filter board of my shortwave PA. I have a dummy load that can handle the 600W output of the PA. And I have a tiny SA to look at the spectrum.
I came across this project that uses a coupler, which attenuates up to 60dB in steps (which would be fine for me):
RF Coupler
But what I'm not sure about is the output impedance of the coupler (PI attenuator), which is not near the 50 Ohms.
The output of my PA is 50 Ohms. Should I change the PI-attenuator?

I assume this is the coupler that the OP is concerned about, image from his link

On the one hand, it is usually good that all RF things that you connect to each other have the same, usually 50 Ω, port impedance. On the other hand, it is not essential if you know what you're doing.
If the output of this coupler is connected through a 50 Ω cable to a Spectrum Analyser (SA) with a good 50 Ω input impedance, then all will be well. The coupler output will 'see' a 50 Ω load. Its output voltage will be what you would expect from the potential division of its source resistance into the 50 Ω load of the SA. The wave it launches into the coax will be fully absorbed by the SA, with no reflection. This means that the connection will have a 'flat' frequency response, even with the coupler mismatch.
One of the drawbacks of having this variable non-50 Ω output impedance is that you have to compute the attenuation for each setting of the switch.
Another drawback is that very often, a spectrum analyser does not have a good 50 Ω input impedance. Then you have a cable with a mismatch at each end. This will resonate, with peaks and suck-outs occurring in the frequency response, at a spacing depending on the length of the cable. Fortunately, this sort of characteristic is very each to spot.
You will have deduced from the above that the 470 Ω shunt resistor is superfluous. It's not low enough to match the cable. It's so high that it's swamped by the 50 Ω load of the SA. You could leave it out with barely any difference in performance. You could replace it with a resistor a bit bigger than 50 Ω, to help match the average series resistor. This would improve the output match of the coupler, and reduce the effect of a poor SA input match.
Many times in my career, I have taken the above advice to its extreme, and used a 'poor man's RF probe', simply a series resistor in the one to a few kΩ range. It's sufficiently high that it barely loads a 50 Ω line. The potential division down into a 50 Ω coax cable into a 50 Ω instrument gives 20 to 40 dB attenuation, just nice for many signal levels met on RF boards.

Thanks Neil for your extensive answer. So if I'd replace the 470 Ohm shunt resistor by a, let's say 60 Ohms resistor, I'd change the series resistor too (around 250 Ohms) in order to get a 20dB attenuation for instance, correct?

Yes, 61, 248, 61 are the right values to give yo a 20 dB 50 ohm attenuator. This would make your setup far less prone to problems from a poor SA input match. I'm not sure what the transformer-based coupler is supposed to be doing however, which may affect your overall attenuation calculations.

According to the author of the linked article, the 1:30 transformer is supposed to do the first 30dB attenuation. Do you think it's inappropriate?

@Laurin not necessarily inappropropriate, I'm just not clear how it's built. Presumably the RF frequency is rather low.

You mean that the frequency gets divided or the amplitude is rather low? I of course need a coupler that does not touch the frequency substantially since I want to measure the harmonics..

@Laurin I mean that a 30 turn transformer is not going to work at any frequency I'd call RF. What frequency are you working at?

I work between 7 and 30MHz

@Laurin I've finally looked all through your link and found a physical picture of the 'coupler'. I'm not sure how it's supposed to work, given that the RF current is going out and back along the same line. It should not work with an ideal transmission line, so presumably it's relying on the line being non-ideal, perhaps by being shunted by the adittional ground path through the enclosure between the BNC connectors. Do you have any links that describe how it was designed, or what its performance is?

No, sadly I couldn't find anything about the design or performance. But I assume it was tested and built by other people

I found another coupler, who seems to have been designed especially to measure harmonics on shortwave frequencies:
link
The designer say, that more PI attenuators could be attached after the -40dB point..

@Laurin Still puzzled about the coupler, it didn't look like it was obvious how it was supposed to work, it didn't look like it was going to be flat, which isn't much good if you're measuring harmonics, I asked the community. Yes, it's not flat. It's not very repeatable. It's not a nice coupler. I can think of two different and better ways to do it.

@Laurin ... so if you go to my question and read Tim Williams' answer, you'll see that the gain depends on the geometry of the coax tails going to the RF connector - so it's not repeatable build to build, but it also because that feature is inductive, it has a rising 6dB/octave frequency characteristic, which you'll need to take into account when measuring your harmonics.

@Laurin Follow the two pdf links in answers/comments to my question linked above - that's how the coupler should be built, to be flat and reproducible..

Thanks for your extensive research! So you're suggesting to build this coupler for example? link
Do you think I could use a Amidon FT-82-43 instead of the T44-2 torroid?

@Laurin that collinsradio link is how that sort of coupler should be built. I know nothing about ferrite grades, and am not going to start remedying that now.  I personally would build a different type of coupler, a capacitive pick-off voltage-divider type, which I would design to be flat over the HF band by absorbing the capacitors into lowpass filters. But that's me, plenty of people have made the current transformer work, with the right ferrite. Do you recall I said the 470 ohm was superfluous? Look at the equivalent positions in the collinsradio coupler. Those values I understand.

Ok, then I'll go for the collinsradio coupler with the correct ferrite. I'll let you know if it worked!
